# Question about queueing state changes with hooks on React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-state

So, I've started studying React by doing class components. There, as far as I understood what I was doing, if I had a

```
this.state = {
  isLoading: false,
  dataToRender: [],
}

this.setState({ isLoading: true }, async () => {
 const data = await fetchData();
 this.setState({ dataToRender: data , isLoading: false });
})

const message => <p>loading...</p>

if (isLoading) return message();

return (
 dataToRender.map
)
```

for displaying a "loading" message whenever I call an API for new data, I could know that the setState "queue" would be executed in an order.
The outer setState would receive a first state change on the first parameter and a function to execute right after it as the second parameter.

The problem is that I'm having a bit of difficulty wrapping my head around ways to achieve this with hooks. I'm assuming doing

```
const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
const [data, setData] = useState([]);

setLoading(async () => {
  setLoading(true)
  const data = await fetchData()
  setData(data);
  return false;
})
```

wouldn't work, right? I feel like the overall logic of building this kind of component logic may be different when using hooks somehow... If anyone could at least point me to concept direction it would be nice.
Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The functions passed as a `useState` state update function are treated as synchronous functions, so you are effectively saving the implicitly returned Promise object into state.

What you should do is factor the asynchronous logic into a function that is called from an event handler, like `onClick`, or is called in a component lifecycle, like `useEffect`.

```
const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
const [data, setData] = useState([]);

const asyncCall = async () => {
  setLoading(true);
  try {
    const data = await fetchData();
    setData(data);
  } catch(error) {
    // handle any errors, logging, etc...
  } finally {
    setLoading(false);
  }
};
```

This will call/enqueue each state update in the order they are enqueued. You should also surround any asynchronous logic in a `try/catch` block so you can handle any rejected promises, clear the loading state in a `finally` so that regardless of resolved/rejected promises, when the code completes it resets the loading state.

Comment: Hi, Drew. About your edit, in my example I considered that the try/catch block was implicit in fetchData(), but this solution with the finally is interesting. The question is: what kind of errors could occur in setData? I mean, once I handled the error in fetchData(), what could result in (error)?

Comment: @Zigoni Oh, I see. I was going on syntax alone since `fetchData` returns a Promise that you are awaiting, it *can* technically return a rejected Promise. I don't think any errors will be thrown from React's state updater function.

Answer (score 1):

There's no callback with the dispatch function of `useState`.

```
  const fn = async () => {
    setIsLoading(true)
    const data = await fetchData()
    setData(data)
    setIsLoading(false)
  })
```

The above function is normally invoked upon an event such as `onClick` or `useEffect`.

Comment: So the useState's setFunctions aren't executed asynchronously? Like, can I be sure that the data will be stored before the loading resumes to false? (thanks by the answer, btw!)

Answer (score 0):

depending on Kent React normally batches these calls so you only get a single re-render, but it's unable to do this in an asynchronous callback (like our promise success and error handlers).
You can use object for value of useState or use useReducer.

```
const [state,setState]=useState({isLoading:false,success:false,isError:false,data:[]})
```

then setting those property on each status.